# ansible - unable to create Azure network security group

Tags: ansible, azure-cloud-shell

I though I correctly followed this [YAML tutorial](https://rollout.io/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started/) (for formatting a YAML file) and this [ansible example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/azure_rm_securitygroup_module.html#examples) from official ansible document to create an `Azure Network Security Group` using following `ansible playbook`. But when I run the playbook in `Azure Cloud Shell`, I get the error shown below:

**Create_network_security_group.yaml**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - azure_rm_securitygroup:
      resource_group: rg-cs-ansible
      name: nsg-cs-web
      rules:
          - name: 'allow_rdp'
            protocol: TCP
            destination_port_range: 3389
            access: Allow
            priority: 1001
            direction: Inbound
          - name: 'allow_web_traffic'
            protocol: TCP
            destination_port_range:
              - 80
              - 443
            access: Allow
            priority: 1002
            direction: Inbound
          - name: 'allow_powershell_remoting'
            protocol: TCP
            destination_port_range:
              - 5985
              - 5986
```

**Error**:

> > [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "value of protocol must be one of: Udp, Tcp, *, got: TCP found in rules"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on official and "latest" documentation at [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html) URL. Notice the example, the case of the protocol is "`Tcp`", not "`TCP`"

Also, the error message you shared is also suggesting to use `Tcp`, `Udp`, `*` as the possible inputs and it got `TCP`.

```
[localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "value of protocol must be one of: Udp, Tcp, *, got: TCP found in rules"}
```

Comment: I changed to `Tcp`. But now I'm getting similar error but a different message although I do have `priority` defined as `priority: 1001` and `priority: 1002` respectively: `[localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: priority found in rules"}`

Comment: for 3rd rule its not there, is it expected ? I am not expect, so asking

Comment: 3rd rule `allow_powershell_remotin` is not having priority defined

Comment: No it's not expected. Also, I have posted a separate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64598994/1232087) since I thought you answered the issue posted above.

Comment: I think it is needed and mandatory , see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_securitygroup_module.html#parameter-rules/priority

Comment: I see. Let me try the priority in third rule, as well.