# ansible playbook for Azure network security group - Error: missing required arguments

Tags: ansible, azure-cloud-shell

Following `YAML playbook` for creating `Azure Network Security Group` DOES specify the `priority` arguments. But I still get the following error when running the playbook in `Azure Cloud Shell`. What may be the cause of the error and how can we fix it?

Remark: I see a similar issue posted on `GitHub` [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55760).

**Create_network_security_group.yaml**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - azure_rm_securitygroup:
      resource_group: rg-cs-ansible
      name: nsg-cs-web
      rules:
          - name: 'allow_rdp'
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range: 3389
            access: Allow
            priority: 1001
            direction: Inbound
          - name: 'allow_web_traffic'
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range:
              - 80
              - 443
            access: Allow
            priority: 1002
            direction: Inbound
          - name: 'allow_powershell_remoting'
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range:
              - 5985
              - 5986
```

**Error**:

> > [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: priority found in rules"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official document located [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_securitygroup_module.html#parameter-rules/priority),  priority is required for each rule defined.

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you for taking time to search for the document related to the issue, and sharing it here.

Comment: glad, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The rules list have some mandatory/rerequired property.

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - azure_rm_securitygroup:
      resource_group: rg-cs-ansible
      name: nsg-cs-web
      rules:
          - name: 'allow_rdp'     <--- required
            priority: 1001        <--- required
            protocol: Tcp
            destination_port_range: 3389
            access: Allow
            direction: Inbound
```